# Application crashing while accessing microphone in iOS 12.1.2 for iPhone XS

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios12, avcapturedevice, xcode9.3, iphone-xs

I am working on iOS application which uses microphone for video capture. When we try to capture video, it asks for microphone permission and crashes immediately after that. We are getting following error:

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: `-[AVCaptureDevice setActiveColorSpace:]` Not supported - use `activeFormat.supportedColorSpaces`"

We have tried searching for this property for AVCaptureDevice. However, not able to find the same.

Answer (score 0):

> We have tried searching for this property for AVCaptureDevice.
>   However, not able to find the same.

**Solution:**

The property `SupportedColorSpaces` really exist under `AVCaptureDevice.ActiveFormat`, make sure you get the correct instance of `AVCaptureDevice`:

To use it, for example:

```
 var videoDevs = AVCaptureDevice.DevicesWithMediaType(AVMediaType.Video);
 var device = videoDevs[0];
 NSNumber[] arr = device.ActiveFormat.SupportedColorSpaces;
```

Document is here:

[AVCaptureDeviceFormat](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/AVFoundation.AVCaptureDeviceFormat/)

[AVFoundation.AVCaptureDevice](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/AVFoundation.AVCaptureDevice/#Public_Properties)

[SupportedColorSpaces](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/AVFoundation.AVCaptureDeviceFormat.SupportedColorSpaces/)